# What can I do with a file open for 'add', if it's submitted via another client

Tags: perforce

With Perforce, I have the following situation:

- Created a new file `foo.txt` in client `client_a`, opened it for **add**
- Shelved `foo.txt` in `client_a`, unshelved it in `client_b`
- Now `foo.txt` is open for **add** in `client_b`
- Submit `foo.txt` in `client_a`

Now my question concerns how I can cleanup `foo.txt` in client_b. Maybe it has a one line change from the depot version that I'd like to keep. Ideally I'd like to do a **resolve** operation against the newly checked in file, but I'm not allowed to do this because it's open for add.

Now I have this file `foo.txt#1 - add change default` in my client.

I can't reopen the file ('nothing changed'), I can't diff it vs the depot ('file not open for edit'), I can't resolve it against the depot ('no files to resolve'), I can't open it for edit ('can't edit, already opened for add').

Is there any way to make perforce reopen this as edit instead of add? I know I can copy it to a temp file, revert, reopen for add, and then recopy the temp file back over, but this seems rather unelegant. Is there any command that can do what I want, or is there a good reason I'm not seeing why it's disallowed?

Answer (score 14):

Only slightly more elegant than the comment in your last paragraph, but you should be able to:

1. Revert `foo.txt` in `client_b`.  Since it was marked for **add** the file will remain on the disk with no changes
2. Sync `foo.txt` with `-k`. This makes the server think you have the latest revision without modifying your local file.
3. Check out `foo.txt` for edit. Diff'ing against the have revision should show the changes.
4. Submit your changes.